# Log4J2 and Tomee Plus 7.0.47 not working

Tags: java, log4j2, apache-tomee

According to [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html), Log4j2 should work with Tomcat7.0.47. I'm using TomEE Plus 7.0.47.

I have a webapplication deployed with a log4j2.xml in my web-inf/classes folder. This is the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/testapp.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.alex" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have a logger declared in a class with name org.alex.util.JSON:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JSON.class);
```

I'm using slf4j-api 1.7.5, and have the following libs added to the tomcat lib:

- slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
- log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar
- log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar
- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0-rc1.jar

If I change the Configuration status to TRACE, I can see my configuration file being picked up and configuration happens as expected. Also I can see the MBeans being added.
However, there's not one logging statement ending up in my logfile. I debugged into the log4j2 Logger, and see that the `isEnabled(...)` method returns `false` because the logger (com.alex.util.JSON) has the level "ERROR" set, while the configuration set the package org.alex to TRACE.
Further investigation shows it uses a DefaultConfiguration configured for level=ERROR, and only root is configured. I'm thinking of a classloader issue, but I can't seem to figure out what the cause is and how to solve it.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This should work on trunk

Btw saw log4j2 has hacks for tomcat and since tomee wraps classloaders not sure they work as expected...

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange. Please raise a ticket for this in the Log4j2 issue tracker so the Log4j team can take a look.

The problem may go away if you put the jar files you mentioned inside WEB-INF/lib instead of in Tomcat's lib folder.

Comment: Hi Remko,

indeed placing the jars in the webapps lib solves the problem. I restored the old situation once more to make sure it didn't work, and it didn't.
Furthermore I noticed that the classloader for the instance of my logger that is created at configuration is org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader, while the classloader of the Logger that is invoked is org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader. I don't know enough of the whole mechanism to judge whether or not this is to be expected, but I'll mention it anyway in the issue report.  
  
Cheers,
Alex

Comment: The problem seems to stem from TomEE's overloaded class loader in comparison to Tomcat's.

Answer (score 0):

To be comple log4j2 relies on servletcontainerinitializer which are called after ejb and app scanning so ejbs can be loaded too early. Doing the same with a tomcat context listener would make it working better